# Identify an eccentric geometric sans serif

Tags: font-identification, typefaces, sans-serif

I have tried a few font identification services, to no avail. It seems to me this should be pretty easy to figure out, given the opinionated letterforms of `E`, `Ö` or `R`, but I've so far been unsuccessful. I have a hunch it could be a well-known classic that I've probably seen many times before. Maybe somebody knows.

[image]

I'd appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. This looks like it's part of a metal structure.  There's a possibility that it isn't an actual font as such, but something which was custom designed. Not everything is necessarily a font you can download.

Comment: It is certainly possible, but I figure the chance that people use a preexisting typeface is also quite high, given that it's faster and easier. Maybe some of the characters were modified, but I'm guessing most of them are part of an actual typeface.

Answer (score 2):

Just to follow up here: I have not been able to find a definitive answer for what we're looking at here, but the best guess is, it's a modified version of [ITC Avant Garde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITC_Avant_Garde).

[image: my quick attempt at reconstructing this Avant Garde based lettering]

The umlauts have been modified to be more easily mountable, with fewer points of contact needed. As for the `E`, I have no idea what's going on here; why it looks like a version of the Euro currency sign, when Avant Garde has a perfectly fine uppercase `E` *and* also an official round alternate style, that would have looked better!

Some of the numbers were adjusted, too, but I will not investigate further.

[image: comparison of two forms of the uppercase E in Avant Garde]